# How to prevent tikz matrix from breaking alignment of "aligned" environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, matrices

How it looks with a matrix:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[matrix]
        {%
            \path node
                {%
                    $%
                        \begin{aligned}
                            &2+2=4\\
                            &3+3+3=9\\
                            &4+4+4+4=16
                        \end{aligned}
                    $
                };\\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How it is supposed to look:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \path node
                {%
                    $%
                        \begin{aligned}
                            &2+2=4\\
                            &3+3+3=9\\
                            &4+4+4+4=16
                        \end{aligned}
                    $
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg excellent option name, don't you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can tell tikz matrix not to mess with `&`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[matrix,ampersand replacement=\&]
        {%
            \path node
                {%
                    $%
                        \begin{aligned}
                            &2+2=4\\
                            &3+3+3=9\\
                            &4+4+4+4=16
                        \end{aligned}
                    $
                };\\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which means `&` keeps its normal use but if you have more than one column in the outer tikz matrix, you need `\&` not `&` to separate the cells.

Answer (score 2):

In a TikZ matrix, `&` receives a different definition than usual (and it becomes an active character).

You can add some protection code to `\start@aligned` (and it will also work for `alignedat`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\make@ampersand@safe}{%
  \ifnum\catcode`\&=\active
    \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\&\lowercase{\endgroup\let~=&}%
 \fi
}
\pretocmd{\start@aligned}{\make@ampersand@safe}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[matrix]
    {%
     \path node
       {%
        $%
         \begin{aligned}
           &2+2=4\\
           &3+3+3=9\\
           &4+4+4+4=16
         \end{aligned}
        $%
      };\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]